# React native retrieving data in real time with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i'm retrieving a document collection as this

```
 const retrieveCollection = async () => {
 
    let questionDocs: Questions[] = [];

    const questionCol = collection(db, "questionsdb");
    const colQuery = query(questionCol);
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(colQuery);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => questionDocs.push(doc.data()));

   
    setQuestions(questionDocs);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveCollection();
  }, []);
```

Each question has an author, when i click a button i want it to show just my questions, if i click it again, it will show all the other questions. This is my function to do it

```
 const [myQuestions, setMyQuestions] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const showMyQuestions = async () => {
      await retrieveCollection();
      console.log(questions);
      const myQuestionFilter = questions?.filter(
        (item) => item.author.uid === user?.uid
      );

      setQuestions(myQuestionFilter!);
    };

    const showAllQuestions = async () => {
      await retrieveCollection();
      const myQuestionFilter = questions?.filter(
        (item) => item.author.uid !== user?.uid
      );

      setQuestions(myQuestionFilter!);
    };

    myQuestions ? showMyQuestions() : showAllQuestions();
  }, [myQuestions]);
```

And this is the button

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setMyQuestions(!myQuestions)}>
        <Text>
          {myQuestions ? "My Questions" : "All Questions"}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I only have questions asked by myself, so when `MyQuestions` is true i should see all questions, and when it's false i should see nothing. But once everything disappears it doesn't comeback. Before i filter the questions array, i call the function `retrieveCollection` to get all questions and then filter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only fetch all your data when the component mounts and store it in `questions`. Its value is further manipulated by `myQuestions`: when true filters `questions` for items you've posted, and when false filter for ones not posted by you. If you toggled it twice, then you would delete everything in `questions` and require another api call to be made.

To avoid this, you should have another variable for `myQuestions` to manipulate, which is used to render the visible questions:

```js
// update your JSX to use this variable
const [visibleQuestions, setVisibleQuestions] = useState(questions || []);
return (
  {/*
   .
   .
   .
  */}
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => {
      const newVal = !myQuestions;
      setMyQuestions(newVal);
       const myQuestionFilter = questions?.filter((item) =>{
         const isMyPost = item.author.uid === user?.uid
         return newVal ? isMyPost : !isMyPost
        );
       setVisibleQuestions(myQuestionFilter)
    }}
  }>
    <Text>
      {myQuestions ? "My Questions" : "All Questions"}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Doing it this way you arent actually deleting the data sent from firebase and thus you wont have to retrieve it again

Comment: So i have the questions array that i won't change, and i have the visibleQuestions that i can manipulate it by fetching from questions without making a new requests, is that right?

Comment: Yahhhhhhhhhhhss

Comment: But to be honest i'm still a bit lost about why what i did was not working. If i filter `questions` and then `setQuestions(filter)` i know that i'm changing questions. So that's why i used async function, to first make the API request and then setQuestions with the retrieved data, and then filter it.

Comment: Lets say you have `numbers =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and  2 filter functions `filterEven` `filterOdd`. Doing `numbers=numbers.filter(filterOdd)` would update `numbers` to equal only the even numbers. The even numbers are lost from the list. If you did `numbers = numbers.filter(filterEven)` afterwards the odd numbers are removed from this list, and because the even numbers never were returned to the list, all numbers would be removed and numbers would be an empty array

Comment: If you did `filterNumbers = numbers.filter(filterOdd)` filteredNumbers would become even numbers.  Now if you were to call `filterNumbers = filterNumbers.filter(filterEven)` you would get the same result as before where the previous filter isnt getting a reset, eventually leading to an empty list. But by calling `filterNumbers = numbers.filter(filterEven)` you are resetting filter back to the original list (`numbers`) and applying the filter to that